# Removing unnecessary header in Hive table export to csv

Tags: hive

How do I remove the text below from an export of a Hive table to local as a csv.

This is the unnecessary line of text that I am getting right at the top, the headers for the columns are displaced to the second row of the csv:

`4/4/2018 19:19 284 WARN  [main] conf.HiveConf (HiveConf.java:initialize(3081)) - HiveConf of name hive.custom-extensions.root does not exist`

This is the code I used to produce the csv.

```
hive -e 'set hive.cli.print.header=true; 
select * from database1.my_table' | sed 's/[\t]/,/g' > /s/myusername/my_table.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can deter the warning messages from being printed to console, and send them to `DRFA` (Daily Rolling File Appender):

```
export HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER="WARN,DRFA"
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried but it still kept showing the error message.

Comment: It seems like the message is being generated by Hive specifically, and I probably need something I could pass within the hive script with a set statement, but I could be wrong.